# How do I install PowerShell?

Tags: software-installation, powershell

Not long ago I read something on Microsoft's website about PowerShell being available for Ubuntu.

How would I go about the install of PowerShell?  I'd appreciate guidance for both **Xenial** & **Trusty**.

Any installation method is fine, whether compiling source or relying on a package-manager.  Source-compiling methods should contain beginner-level detail.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As of February 2017, Microsoft has made these available though a public repository which brings all the repository goodness.  Details [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-linux?view=powershell-7).

Here are the instructions to install the latest version of PowerShell on 16.04.

```
# Import the public repository GPG keys
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -

# Register the Microsoft Ubuntu repository
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft.list

# Update the list of products
sudo apt-get update

# Install PowerShell
sudo apt-get install -y powershell

# Start PowerShell (MS renamed main executable at launch to be more Linux-like)
pwsh
```

Comment: Here's the current doc link:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/setup/installing-powershell-core-on-linux?view=powershell-6

Comment: Needed `apt-get install apt-transport-https` on 16.04 (docker).

Comment: @arun Did you need that as a prerequisite to install Powershell or to enable a particular feature/cmdlet?

Comment: to install Powershell

Comment: I'll take a look and update  Thanks

Comment: @Arun did you download and install the package or use the repo?

Answer (score 10):

For debian install files ('.deb') and other downloads, see [PowerShell releases](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/) on GitHub.

Direct download links, with SHA256 hashes:

- 14.04: [powershell_6.0.0-alpha.16-1ubuntu1.14.04.1_amd64.deb](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/download/v6.0.0-alpha.16/powershell_6.0.0-alpha.16-1ubuntu1.14.04.1_amd64.deb)

  ```
  FB0002D6D57D900D0BA16C13C4EB0B84CA9D1AEA5EAF4DDBC0F7E8F3D582A2DF
  ```
- 16.04: [powershell_6.0.0-alpha.16-1ubuntu1.16.04.1_amd64.deb](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/download/v6.0.0-alpha.16/powershell_6.0.0-alpha.16-1ubuntu1.16.04.1_amd64.deb)

  ```
  96A647EFA64C704958CEAFA89F319950A3B729C161CB77C286561AF3CD3BFC1E
  ```

---

Download the DEB, verify the checksum, and then let Ubuntu Software Center take care of installing it.  See [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToSHA256SUM) on how to verify the download.  Basically, enter the following command:

```
sha256sum powershell_*.deb
```

Comment: They added "man" pages for commands so you will get those when you install powershell. On their site they point to MSDN (the nerver ;-) ) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/console/powershell.exe-command-line-help

Comment: Here are the english docs: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs

Comment: These direct links now point to outdated downloads.  Please follow the link to GitHub or install the repo and use the package manager

Answer (score 4):

### Ubuntu 14.04 and later

PowerShell can be installed as a snap package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. To install the PowerShell snap package open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install powershell --classic
```

To start PowerShell from the terminal type:

```
snap run powershell
```

Comment: This works on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 2):

### [`PowerShell`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell) Release: [`v6.0.0-beta.4`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/tag/v6.0.0-beta.4)

---

### Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr)

**[Method #1] ~ APT**

```
wget https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/download/v6.0.0-beta.4/powershell_6.0.0-beta.4-1ubuntu1.14.04.1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./powershell_*.deb
```

**[Method #2] ~ dpkg**

```
wget https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/download/v6.0.0-beta.4/powershell_6.0.0-beta.4-1ubuntu1.14.04.1_amd64.deb
dpkg -i powershell_*.deb 
apt-get install -f
```

### Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus)

**[Method #1] ~ APT**

```
wget https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/download/v6.0.0-beta.4/powershell_6.0.0-beta.4-1ubuntu1.16.04.1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./powershell_*.deb
```

**[Method #2] ~ dpkg**

```
wget https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/download/v6.0.0-beta.4/powershell_6.0.0-beta.4-1ubuntu1.16.04.1_amd64.deb
dpkg -i powershell_*.deb 
apt-get install -f
```

---

- [PowerShell - Releases (GitHub)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases)
- [PowerShell - Documentation](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/tree/master/docs)
- [PowerShell - Beginner's Guide](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/docs/learning-powershell/powershell-beginners-guide.md)
- [PowerShell - Command-line Debugging](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/docs/learning-powershell/debugging-from-commandline.md)

Comment: `apt install ./foo.deb` will resolve dependencies, so you don't need a `apt-get install -f` after it.

Comment: Why bother updating this when MS has published a repo? https://askubuntu.com/a/925458/158442