# Windows command line emulator for Linux

Tags: command-line, windows, emulation

Is there a way to emulate a Windows CMD in Linux.
What i need is full functionality as if I use the real CMD running in Windows.
I want to be able to practice tutorials about WIN CMD, using my Linux PC.

Searching the Internet didn't help a lot.

Thanks for your help :-)

Edit:

Thank you for all your answers. I really appreciated your time spending.
I mostly wanted to practice WMIC commandline using my main computer running under Ubuntu.
I tried most of the solutions proposed but what worked better was virtualBox ;-)

Comment: Powershell is actually available for installation on Ubuntu. See https://askubuntu.com/q/878932/295286

Comment: use powershell and that's all, they ported it in linux

Answer (score 2):

1. Have you tried using wine for this? This isn't running natively through your box, but rather through a compatibility layer. As user535733 stated, "full functionality" is a very difficult term, windows is windows for a reason, and they're not releasing their source code any time soon. Most commands on "cmd" should work in the wine version, but maybe not all:
   https://wiki.winehq.org/Cmd
2. Alternatively, you can use the FOSS "Powershell" for this. It has/should have the same syntax as the windows equivalent. Someone online forked the original windows program:
   https://github.com/powershell/powershell
3. And ultimately, the only other way i can think of having (near) native cmd/powershell is via gpu passthrough. Be warned, this is a difficult process. It all depends on what functionality you require out of your cmd/powershell environment.

If none of these fulfil your needs, consider dual booting with windows, or continue with your search.

Answer (score 0):

[DosBox](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/dosbox) is a full emulator for x86 with a DOS-compatible command-line OS built-in and good support for DOS programs, including games which required VGA (or EGA/CGA) graphics.

So you can write batch programs and run DOS utilities etc.

It's not clear from your question whether you wanted to be able to run Windows programs - if so, DOSBox won't help and you'll need something like Wine.

Comment: DOS is not MS-DOS they removed a lot of the original DOS in future releases and even created some new commands like the `start` utility

Comment: Sorry Egon I'm finding it difficult to understand what you mean, have you got a link?  `start` is a standard command from Win95 onwards, so I guess you're saying they added that in to DosBox for greater compatibility?